# Do we have an Interface which provided all the styles in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I have a **Style** struct

```
Struct Style {
    var borderColor : UIColor

   init(borderColor : UIColor){
       self.borderColor = UIColor
   }
}
```

Anyone can now apply styling using **Style** object. But now I want to give users flexibility of passing any number of styling not just **borderColor**.

For example :

```
Struct Style {
    var borderColor : UIColor
    var someStyle : someStyleType
   init(borderColor : UIColor, someStyle: someStyleType, ...){
       self.borderColor = borderColor
       self.someStyle = someStyle
   }
}
```

If I will keep on typing different type of style there no of properties of Style is going to be very large. So what I was thinking, is to keep it dynamic in some way. Can somebody help me with some approach?

I want something like this, can we do this?

we can pass any number of parameters using the constructor, like

```
Struct Style: SomeInterfaceWhichProvideAllTheStyle {
   init(borderColor : UIColor, someStyle: someStyleType, anyNoOfArguments){
       super.borderColor = borderColor
       super.textColor = textColorStyle
   }
}
```

Comment: "to keep it dynamic in some way" In what way exactly?

Comment: There are exactly *two* styles that iOS natively supports - light and dark. A good way to  configure the colors for those styles is through the asset catalog. If you want more styles, you have to invent your own thing, and you should explain what exactly it is that you want to do - others cannot read your mind.

Comment: thanks, Sweeper, I have made the edits, that explais what I actually want to achieve.